# Are natural or artificial pools of water (like ponds) carbon positive, negative or neutral?

Tags: climate-change, carbon-cycle, carbon-capture

Are natural or artificial pools of water (like ponds) carbon positive, negative or neutral? They store carbon, but anaerobes release methane, don't they?

Comment: What size of water bodies are we talking about? Which climate? Which inflow of nutrition? Which time scale?

Comment: @Erik like, a run-of-the-mill type